# Query regarding deep copy of pointers inside a structure to another structure

Tags: c, pointers, deep-copy

I have a query regarding the deep copy in C.

I can't share the real code but my code looks something like this:

```
struct a {
  char *t1; 
  char *t2; 
  int a; 
  int b; 
};
```

I have a  `s1` of type struct a whose values are dynamically assigned. I have another struct `s2` to which I want to copy the contents of `struct a` . Since I have pointers, I need to do deep copy, so that i won't lose the values when I `free(struct s1)`.

For doing deep copy, to beFin with, I have dynamically allocated struct `s2` like below:

```
struct s2 = malloc(sizeof(struct a));
```

and now in another function, I am using `memmove` to copy the contents of `s1` to `s2`:

```
memmove(s1.t1, &s2.t1, length_of_t1)
```

Is this the correct way of doing the deep copy?

Comment: 1,) s2 needs to be a pointer 2.) the sequence of parameters in `memove()` is wrong 3.) you copying the pointer only, if you called memmove() correctly it would be the same as `s2->t1 = s1.t1`. That's no deep copy

Comment: If calling `free(pointer_to_s1)` does not free the memory location that `t1` or `t2` point to (i.e. they are `malloc`'d), then they are just variables and you do not need a deep copy.

Comment: You should provide a [mre] including how to actually use the structs! Scenarios might differ pretty much depending on how you actually use the structs and create the backup!

Comment: In sequence to @the_bond_007: Your problem actually might not be the deep copying, but the freeing of the old texts within `s2`! Assuming `s1` is dynamically allocated (why at all???) and is going to be freed, but you need a backup in `s2` (assuming statically allocated?) then you actually simply *can* memcopy `s1` to `s2` **but** simply doing so leaves a memory leak for not freeing `s2->t1` and `s2->t2` before getting overwritten! So free these *before* copying.

Comment: The order of arguments to `strcpy()` and `memcpy()` — destination first, then source —  seem unintuitive until your realize that they mimic assignment (`dest = src``).

Comment: As an aside: If you have a reasonable maximum length for the strings (let's call it MAX_LEN) it may be easiest to declare the strings as true arrays, not pointers, e.g. `struct a { char t1[MAX_LEN];  char t2[MAX_LEN]; int a; int b; };`. That way, you can simply assign these structs, no memcpy at all necessary. The array contents is copied over as well.

Comment: Referring to my previous comment and @Peter-ReinstateMonica 's: `struct a* s1 = malloc(sizeof(*s1); /* assign s1->t1, s1->t2 to dynamically allocated strings */ struct a s2 = { .t1 = NULL, .t2 = NULL; } void backupAndFreeS1() { free(s2.t1); free(s2.t2); s2 = *s1; /* copies pointers and values */ free(s1); s1 = NULL; }`

Comment: @Aconcagua I don't quite understand your comment, let alone what it has to do with mine ;-). Do you mean to use true arrays for t1 and t2, as I suggested? Why then the initialization with NULL? Why first initialize with null and then free!? Best would probably be to write an answer for more complex suggestions.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Actually I intended referring to the copy assignment instead of using `memcpy` – that's fine for both the pointers *and* the included arrays. The code example above still maintains the original pointers and is drawn for a scenario where the deep copying actually *might* be obsolete, which the really unsharp problem description and lack of [mre] still leave open (possibly [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Why initialising with `NULL` and then `free`? I try to dig behind the question itself, which requires interpretation. The dynamic allocation indicates possibly creating `s1` *multiple* times, and the function is intended to always backup the last instance going to be freed. I should have explained better, agree. But with this scenario drawn the deep copying simply might not be necessary. Speculative, admitted… Even if we indeed need deep copying, if the object `s2` is re-used then still the requirement to free `s2->t1` and `s2->t2` might arise!

Comment: So behind the little information given there are quite a number of possible implications hidden, which my comments are intended to reveal, showing up the urgent need for describing the use case precisely as well as providing a [mre], rather than to give a possible solution (thus remaining comments).

Answer (score 2):

No, what you're trying to do is a shallow copy.

You probably want this:

```
struct a {
  char *t1; 
  char *t2; 
  int a; 
  int b; 
};
...
// assuming s1 points to a valid struct a
// and s1->t1 and s1->t2 point to valid C strings,
// the following lines perform a deep copy of s1 into s2

struct *s2 = malloc(sizeof(struct a));  // allocate new struct

memcpy(s2, s1, sizeof(struct a));       // copy the struct
// *s1 = *s1;                           // you also can use this instead of memcpy

s2->t1 = malloc(strlen(s1->t1) + 1);    // allocate space for t1
strcpy(s2->t1, s1->t1);                 // copy the bytes

s2->t2 = malloc(strlen(s1->t2) + 1);    // allocate space for t2
strcpy(s2->t2, s1->t2);                 // copy the bytes
```

BTW: I'm using `memcpy` as there is no overlap between source and destination.

Discalaimer: this is untested, unoptimized code and error checks are omitted for brevity.

Comment: memcpy would need a third (length) param; strypy is the way to go here, since we rely on null terminated strings in s1 anyway (strlen). I took the liberty to correct the code.

Comment: Another aside: Since about 1983, you can simply assign the structs instead of memcpying, e.g. `memcpy(s2, s1, sizeof(struct a));` can be written as a simple `*s2 = *s1;`.

Comment: I think the use case is too unclear to present this as the solution, we might not need to copy the strings at all...

Comment: @Aconcagua Well, "deep copy" is a pretty clear demand. Without it, you can simply assign the structs and be done.

Comment: I also corrected a typo where `strlen(s2->t2)` was taken as the length to allocate `s2->t2`;-).

Comment: Apart from, I would have stored the data lengths in an intermediate variable and still used `memcpy` (`size_t len = strlen(...) + 1; malloc(len); memcpy(x, y, len);`) for efficiency (not needing to lookup the terminating null character twice).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The point is: While deep copying indeed has been requested it might turn out to be actually unnecessary, depending on the use case (XY problem already?). The lack of an MRE simply leaves this issue open…